# Tensorflow Numpy do not run with Python2.7 and 3.5 both on ipython notebook

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Eh..I upgraded my Python from 2.7 to 3.5 on iPython Jupyter Notebook, using Anaconda, and then all messed up..

I can use

- tensorflow with kernel Python 3.5 
  and
- numpy with kernel Python 2.7 
  but not both...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may just need to re-install numpy for python3. Something like pip3 install numpy or sudo apt-get install python3-numpy. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for response. No it did no help. I eventually deleted anaconda and everything from my Mac, and reinstall everything all over... Now numpy works fine but not tensorflow :(    Thanks anyway.  I made them work once, I should be able to make it again. It's just frustrating that I do not even know why they worked

Comment: Have you tried the TensorFlow Docker images? They can remove a lot of the hassle of installing. Not ideal on OSX, but probably just fine if you don't need GPU support.

Comment: If you have both versions of Python in Anaconda, they are probably in separate environments. Each environment has its own set of packages, so you need to switch into the relevant environment (`source activate envname`) and then `conda install` the packages you need.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem.
in my way, i think this problem is about to virtualenv . so I installed the same version of tensorflow and numpy at same storage.

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

[image: Jupiter Screenshot]